# Ajax based suggestions list, and replacement

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to create a suggested items list on my website, similar to that of Facebook's "suggested friends" list.

I have a list of 10 suggested items, which comes from a mysql query.
The user has an option to 'x' the item or accept the item, after which that list item should be replaced using AJAX.  The replacement item comes from the same query, but not necessarily the 11th item in the original table.  The mysql query will change based on the user's input.

The only way I can think to accomplish this is to get jquery to grab the ID's of all 10 items, send them to AJAX which will pull up the query and compare the lists, and spit out the one that is new.

This seems messy, and probably an unnecessary amount of information being sent to AJAX. Is there a more clever alternative to this?

Comment: Is there a fixed set of items a user can get?

Comment: no, the list could be endless. Similar to something like Twitter. If they follow or ignore an item, the suggestions will change to reflect

Comment: I'm sorry, not familiar with twitter =)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can not totally avoid the query process, but you can do next:

Get an amount of 100 items for example, then process them with JS to show the n first items

```
var items = [...];
var deleted = [];

function show(){
   for(i=0; i<10; i++){
      where_to_add.innerHTML += items[ i ];
   }
}

function delete( n ){
    deleted.push( items[ n ] );
    items.splice(n,1);
    show();
}
```

Now you can minimize the amount of requests to the server by defining the amount of items to load at a time.

Comment: Forgot to add: you can send the data in `deleled` array to the server to process it in the query;